# FAQ still references Theoretical Physics

Tags: discussion, status-completed

The FAQ still mentions Theoretical Physics, which was closed (and is now essentially part of Physics):

> Physics, ask on https://physics.stackexchange.com/ or http://theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/ if it is about physical theories or closed form solutions rather than computational methods.

This should be changed to only reference Physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference to Theoretical Physics has been deleted.